Particle system as fluid effector
How can I have particles from a particle system be a fluid effector?
I have:

plane: emitter particle system with physics --> fluid --> type effector collision
icospheres: instanced particles (falling down) with physics --> fluid --> type effector collision
fluid domain
fluid (where are the splashes?)

This Reddit post says it is possible, but "fluid sim will not allow its collision objects (Effectors) to float or be moved by the fluid. The Effectors can affect the fluid (eg. make a splash) but not vice versa". This one-way interaction (particles affect fluid, fluid does not affect particles) is good enough for me.



Well, the Reddit post is misleading. A particle system cannot be used as an effector - not even as source in a Flow object with liquid simulations, only for smoke simulations. Only if you would use objects rendered for the particles, then bake the simulation to mesh objects and make them effectors it might work. But this means the particle simulation cannot be changed anymore afterwards. The one answering the question was ignoring the part with the particle system and focusing on the effector/fluid relationship. Or misinterpreting particle system as the fluid particles created by the domain.
